# Why does php + memcache have a very slow response

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, memcached

I have a custom framework with a custom class that handles the database connection, queries, etc. 
In this database class i've decided to use Memcache to speed up my page response time.

I save the data in Memcache like *'query-' . md5($sql_query) = 'SQL results'* and then when i need to query the database if i already have this key in Memcache then i'll do a ->get on it and use that value.

The problem is that it works ok(ish) in the begining but after a period it begins to slow down significantly.

For example the initial load speed without Memcache was:

```
Server Software:        Apache
Server Hostname:        www.site.ro
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        40737 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   10.299 seconds
Complete requests:      50
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      2054600 bytes
HTML transferred:       2036850 bytes
Requests per second:    4.85 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       2059.816 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       205.982 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          194.82 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

and with Memcache it's something like this:

```
Server Software:        Apache
Server Hostname:        www.site.ro
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        40737 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   114.513 seconds
Complete requests:      50
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      2054600 bytes
HTML transferred:       2036850 bytes
Requests per second:    0.55 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       18141.600 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1814.160 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          22.12 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

Here is an image with the Memcache admin panel:
[image]

top snippet:
[image]

Do you have any ideea/suggestions as to what i am i doing wrong or how should i configure Memcache to actually speed up not slow down the application?

Comment: The first thing I would check is, are you using a single Memcache connection (good) or opening a new connection for each query (very bad)?

Comment: i have a singleton class that is instantiated at the beginning of the application, so it runs only once for each page request (not for each db request).

Comment: what are the server configuration you have like ram, cpu etc. can you add those details also?

Comment: so many things can go wrong.... what's the bottleneck?

Comment: specs are: ubuntu 14.0.4, HDD 20 GB, 2GB RAM, 1 core CPU, LAMP environment. The bottleneck seems to be at the ->get method of Memcache. 1 get takes almost 1 second (which is A LOT). also added a top snippet in main post

Comment: you have to go deeper. my guess: Not enough RAM and heavy swapping? unlikely: CPU saturated? network?

Comment: ok it seems fine but I think you need to check Memcache configuration also like how much memory you have aloted it, max connections etc. there are many possibilities that can cause such issues. I suggest try aloting more memory and less no of connections then see the performance

Comment: It may be an issue of Paging Memory to Hard Disk by operating system